# How to run bash command as ubuntu user?

Tags: bash

I want to create alias with bash file for user "ubuntu", for example `test.sh` :
when I run `test.sh` file the `alias` work only for root user.
how to set alias to "ubuntu" user via bash file?

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
alias ll="ls -al"
```

Comment: put the line `alias ll="ls -al"` in the bashrc file of ubuntu user home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `test.sh` you'll briefly have that alias available in the bash instance that starts when you run that script. The alias will be gone when that bash instance exits, which is at the end of your script.

If you want the alias to be available you will need to source the `test.sh` file:

```
source test.sh
```

or

```
. test.sh
```

You can of course specify the full path to `test.sh`, and you can leave out the shebang ( `#!/bin/bash` it has no function when you source a file).